# Interpreting graph of mitosis and meiosis

Tags: homework, meiosis, mitosis

[image]

**Note : Consider the y axis as 1,2,3,4(not 2,3,4) and x axis as time. Roman numerals should be considered from I-X ( some are not correct here )**

**Which stages show mitosis?**
My answer : III-V

**Which stages show meiosis?**
My answer : VII-X

Am I right ?

Comment: I think there is no problem in your arguments. The part IV-V can also be considered a part of interphase (G1 phase), and not mitosis, though it is still ambiguous in the diagram.

Comment: @SatwikPasani Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe III → IV is mitosis and VII → X would be meiosis. As Jam explained in comments below, the stationary points of the graph (II → III or VI → VII ) do not count as part of either process.

Comment: DNA is replicated during interphase, not mitosis. So I → II cannot be part of mitosis.

Comment: Ah I see where I went wrong. Would II to IV and VI to X be correct?

Comment: I think III → IV and VII → X would be the right answer. The gap between II → III is referred to as a separate phase outside of mitosis (G2, which is part of interphase). It might seem redundant since it looks like nothing's actually happening on the graph between II → III or VI → VII (and I can see why you'd suggest starting there) but there are other cellular processes that happen during these gap phases :)

Comment: Penny has dropped, thank you that is very helpful! :)

Comment: Np - If you edit your answer, I can upvote it. The site won't let me change my previous vote until the answer is edited.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can conclude that if you consider only **chromosome number changes** (excluding DNA and Chromatid number changes, which would dramatically change the graphical interpretation):

• I to II would represent ***anaphase*** (note chromosome doubled in a single cell)

•II to III would represent ***karyokinesis***

•III to IV would be ***cytokinesis*** ( note the chromosome number returns to its initial for the given cell taken into consideration)

•IV to V would be a complex of interphase , prophase and metaphase

• V to VI can be again anaphase

• I have interpreted that from VI to VII there has been a chromatid doubling but the number of chromosome remains same

•Steps VII to X are clearly the steps of ***meiosis***

**So to conclude steps I to VI are mitosis and VII to X are meiosis**